# ¿Como resolver el bloqueo del puerto 80?

Tags: windows, apache

Hola a todos soy nuevo en programación web y como muchas personas antes de subir una pagina web uno hace pruebas en local, yo uso Xampp y hasta ayer funcionaba perfecto hasta que hoy intente abrirlo y salio esto:

> Apache: Problem detected!
>  Apache: Port 80 in use by "Unable to
>   open process" with PID 4!
>  Apache: WILL NOT start without the
>   configured ports free!
>  Apache: You need to
>   uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>  Apache: or
>   reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

He estado leyendo y una solución es con CMD `net stop was /y`, pero no funciona o no lo hago correctamente si alguno me puede ayudar :'(, uso win8.1 x64 en AMD, gracias de ante mano.

Comment: A mi me paso porque tenia skype iniciado, prueba a pararlo y volver a iniciarlo

Comment: No has intentado matar la aplicación de dicho puerto en apache y luego reiniciarlo, para probar, sino puedes probar con el puerto con una redirección al puerto 23, como se hace ídem como el compañero de arriba.
Yo en su día tuve un problema similar y así me soluciono,
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es utilizar **netstat** y unos cuantos parámetros desde la consola en windows (`-o` muestra el PID, `-a` todas las conexiones y `-n` direcciones ip)

```
c:\Jack> netstat -oan
```

Luego que ya sabemos si o no está en uso.. ahí mismo con el parámetro `-o` podemos tener acceso al no. de proceso o PID .. ya con ese dato podemos abrir el administrador de tareas, eso bastaría para saber su nombre y matarlo si es lo que necesitan.. pero si es un proceso global y no aparece en el administrador de tareas, no hay de otra más que seguir utilizando la consola para averiguar de donde diablos salío la aplicación que utiliza el puerto que necesitan.

Bueno, lo siguiente entonces es saber el nombre de la aplicación dueña del proceso y para esto utilizamos el comando tasklist con otro par de parámetros (`-svc` para obtener el nombre del servicio, `-FI` para aplicar un filtro de búsqueda)

```
c:\Jack> tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 1428"
```

En este caso de ejemplo quiero conocer el nombre de la aplicación con **PID 1428** que fue lo que encontré utilizando netstat .. y el resultado de la ejecución de tasklist es el nombre de la aplicación.

Ya para finalizar vamos a utilizar el comando taskkill enviando como parámetros `-F` para forzar el cierre de la aplicacion y `-PID` para especificar el número de proceso a matar.

```
c:\Jack> taskkill /F /PID 1428
```

Tu harias exactamente lo mismo pero con el proceso que este usando el puerto 80 [Ref](http://qbit.com.mx/blog/2012/05/08/como-saber-que-puertos-estan-ocupados-y-que-programa-los-utiliza-en-windows/).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El puerto 80 es el puerto por defecto para que el servidor reciba la comunicación por HTTP. Al parecer tienes otro servidor instalado en tu computador que ya utiliza este puerto. Tienes dos opciones:

1. Como indica Gemasoft en su respuesta, puedes buscar el proceso de la aplicación (el proceso del otro servidor web) y cerrarlo. Así, al levantar tu servidor Apache podrá ejecutar sin problemas puesto que el puerto 80 está libre.
2. Cambia el puerto que utiliza alguna de estas aplicaciones. En este caso, yo cambiaría el puerto de Apache para que en lugar de apuntar al puerto 80 apunte a un número diferente. El número del puerto puede variar entre 0 y 65536. Elige un número diferente al 80, por ejemplo 4000. En Apache, puedes cambiar el número del puerto al modificar el archivo **httpd.conf** que se debe encontrar en `<ruta_instalación_xampp>/apache/conf` (`<ruta_instalación_xampp>` usualmente es `C:\xampp`, en mi caso no lo es, por eso su valor depende de la ruta donde hayas instalado xampp) y buscar las siguientes líneas:

   ```
   Listen 80
   # más líneas...
   ServerName localhost:80
   ```

   Cambia el número 80 por el número de puerto que deseas. Para este ejemplo, sería 4000.

   ```
   Listen 4000
   # más líneas...
   ServerName localhost:4000
   ```

   Como Apache está siendo levantado por XAMPP, te recomiendo que vayas al Panel de Control y selecciones la opción **Config**. En la ventana que aparece, selecciona la opción **Configuración de Puertos y Servicios**. En la ventana que aparece, selecciona el tab **Apache** y cambia el puerto principal a 4000. Dejo imagen como referencia:

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

   Ahora inicia tu servidor Apache. Debería ejecutar sin problemas. Para acceder a él y verificar que está en ejecución sin problemas, entra a la siguiente url:

   http://localhost:4000/
   (Ojo que ahora tenemos que indicar el puerto en la URL. Como 80 es el puerto por defecto, cuando accedes a `http://localhost/` es como si accedieras a `http://localhost:80/`)

   En el caso que no quieras cambiar el puerto de Apache, puedes optar por cambiar el puerto de la otra aplicación que hace uso del puerto 80.

Si estás en un ambiente controlado, digamos tu computadora de trabajo personal, y esto es sencillamente para aprendizaje, puedes usar la primera opción si no necesitas la otra aplicación, y si quieres que ambas convivan puedes usar la segunda opción. Si estás en un ambiente ligeramente controlado donde solo tienes control sobre Apache, te recomiendo la segunda opción. Si es un servidor de producción, me preguntaría por qué tienes otra aplicación que ya escucha el puerto 80 y analizaría la situación.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te han dicho, tienes el puerto bloqueado porque otra aplicación lo está usando. Puedes probar a cambiar el puerto en la configuración de `XAMPP` ( o de apache en su defecto) y/o buscar mediante "netstat" la aplicación que lo este bloqueando. En mi caso fue que `apache` no se había cerrado cuando le ordene el cierre por el control de `Xampp`, y tuve que reiniciar el equipo. (Habrás reiniciado,no ?)

Answer (score 0):

En el  ***RegEdit*** de windows

Ir a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP

Cambie el valor de "inicio" a 4, lo que significa movilidad.

Reinicie su computadora.

Fuente: [https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/28028/pid4-usando-el-puerto-80][1]